# Compiling a GO program on Windows to be Deployed on Linux

Tags: linux, windows, go

I would like to develop on a windows environment and have installed go 1.10.1... I need to deploy my program on a linux however. Is there a way to build the go program and specify to build for linux. I have seen tons of documentation for going from linux to windows but not the other way around.

The most promising example I have tried:

```
set GOOS=linux 
set GOARCH=amd64 
go build filename.go
```

--> which just builds an exe..

Comment: Did you type GOOS or GOOOS ?

Comment: GOOS. Must of fat fingered it.

Comment: Is your desired target part of the list when you run `go tool dist list` ?

Comment: You are on the right path. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-build-go-executables-for-multiple-platforms-on-ubuntu-16-04 has more information.

Comment: I doubt this is the cause, but did you consider upgrading to the freshly available 1.10.*2* ?

Comment: Is it in fact an exe or does it just have a .exe filename suffix?

Comment: @Marged it is not in my dist list. How do I make install it? Apologize for the novice questions. Just decided to make the jump from the .net world to go about a week ago. Love the language, still struggling with this sort of stuff however.

Comment: @Volker good point. I saw .exe and assumed it was a windows build. I will check once I confirm I have the proper Linux dist tools.

Comment: @LCaraway: I only downloaded https://dl.google.com/go/go1.10.2.windows-amd64.zip, unpacked it (in my case using 7-zip) and had all I needed to compile for Linux. Dump your 1.10.1 and do a fresh download

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can confirm that what you are trying to achieve works for me on Windows 7 and Windows 10 with go 1.10.2.
To check that your go install supports your desired target, run this command:

```
go tool dist list | find "linux/amd64"
```

You should make sure that you set the environment variables without any additional or hidden spaces, set them this way:

```
set GOOS=linux
set GOARCH=amd64
```

Then verify, for example this way:

```
echo !%GOOS%!
echo !%GOARCH%!
```

If the combination is not valid, you should get this message:

> cmd/go: unsupported GOOS/GOARCH pair linux /amd64

After this run your build:

```
go build -v -x -o foreign_linux foreign.go
```

Following Volkers advice you can check if the created binary really is a linux binary:

```
type foreign_linux
```

You will receive some cryptic characters, but at the beginning of the first line should be `ELF`. If it is an exe, you will see `MZ`.

[image]

Comment: success! Side note, I had to use CMD to make this work. the above steps did not work for Powershell and I suspect it has to do with setting the GOOS and GOARCH environment variables.